# scroll instagram followers following

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

i wanted to get instagram followers/following user list.
previously used this selenium python script is working:

```
scroll_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
sleep(5)
# height variable
last_ht, ht = 0, 1
while last_ht != ht:
    last_ht = ht
    sleep(2)
    # scroll down and retrun the height of scroll
    ht = browser.execute_script(""" 
    arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
    return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """, scroll_box)
```

i've also tried this solution but still error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54174682/11727107

is there a change from the instagram dev?
and now how to do scrolling.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

work with this code:

```
scroll_box  = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_9-49']")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31737293)

Comment: @David Although code-only answers are considered low quality, they are still considered answers (even if they are wrong answers). The appropriate response is to downvote, not to vote to delete (unless it is a new answer to an older question that basically just repeats existing older answers).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the hint, I'll feel better too using the down-vote option, will consider it for applying cases.